# This question appears to lack a clear problem statement. Is it a good audit?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, disputed-review-audits, minimal-reproducible-example

I just failed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/33346469) review audit, covering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74573307/6471538) question.

I saw this question and gravitated to the fact that it lacks a clear problem statement. The question asker rightfully mentions that their code does not compile, but does not describe what, if any, error messages were generated. This, based on my understanding, should merit closure. While the question got a good answer that I agree with, that doesn't change the fact that the question itself is little more than "My code doesn't work in some compilers, help".

Is this question good or not?

Comment: The question seems clear to me.  The OP wrote code using a relatively new language feature that only worked in one of three major C++ compilers and wanted to know if GCC was compiling something it shouldn't or if Clang and MSVC were rejecting something that they should accept.